# Django Form Error : <ul class="errorlist"><li>language<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a list of values.</li></ul></li></ul>

Tags: python, django

This is my view.I want to add a manytomanyfield through text rather than checkbox so that I can create new and get old ones. I want user to just split each language with space

```
class CreateBooksView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = "/books/login"
    form_class = CreateBooksForm
    template_name = "books/create.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


    def form_valid(self,form):
        tag_list=[]
        books = form.save(commit=False)
        books.author = self.request.user
        tags = form.cleaned_data['language']
        print(tags)
        tag_list=[Language.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)[0] for tag in 
        tags.split()]
        for tag in tag_list:
            a = books.language.add(tag)
        books.language = a    
        books.save()
        return super(CreateBooksView,self).form_valid(form)


    def form_invalid(self,form):
        print (form.errors)
        return super(CreateBooksView,self).form_invalid(form) 

from django import forms
from books.models import Book
class CreateBooksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = "name","about","language","image"
        widgets = {
            'language': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 2}),
```

This is my models.So the ManytoManyField that I want to get filtered is language.

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    about =models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image)  
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language,related_name='book') 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='bauthor')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)
```

Comment: Your language field in your ```ModelForm``` expects a list of ids and not a string. Try taking out that field from the form and adding an additional non-model TextField to the form. Use the contents of that field for creating the m2m in your view

Comment: @Chris can you please show me how it is done . Add  answer may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language field in your `ModelForm` expects a list of ids and not a string. What I would suggestis taking out the language field from your `ModelForm` and add a non-model field to handle the tags.

```
#forms.py

class CreateBooksForm(forms.ModelForm):

    tags = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 2}))

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = "name","tags", "about","image"
```

and then handle the tags in your view

```
...

def form_valid(self,form):
    tag_list=[]
    books = form.save(commit=False)
    books.author = self.request.user
    tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
    books.save() # must be save before adding m2m
    tag_list=[Language1.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)[0] for tag in tags.split()]

    for tag in tag_list:
        a = books.language.add(tag) 
    books.save()
    return super(CreateBooksView,self).form_valid(form)
```